# Random walk question on textbook

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Here is some statement from my textbook.
Let $T$ be the time it takes for the random walk to reach $0$ or $N$, and let
$$G(j)=E[T|\,X_0=j] = j(N-j),\quad j=1,\cdots,n-1 \qquad (1.18)$$
By (1.18), we have the expected time that it takes the random walk from the interior point(next to the boundary point) to reach a boundary is $k-3$. We therefore get the equation
$$r(k) = 1+\frac{1}{2}[(k-3)+r(k)]$$
where $r(k)=E(T_k-T_{k-1})$ for $k=3,\cdots,N$ and $T_k$ denotes the first time at which the number of distincte points visited equals $k$.

I have a question at the bottom of the page. Why the expected time is $k-3$ and how do we get the recurrence?

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: The thing about images is an actual rule here; breaking it usually results in questions being closed. You also should not really need that much content in order to pose your question; in particular the part before the random walk on the circle is *almost* entirely unnecessary for your question (except inasmuch as the first result is used in the renewal argument in the circle problem).

Comment: Anyway, the $k-3$ comes because before the renewal you have visited $k-1$ states, and then in the recursive case you move to a visited state rather than an unvisited state. Now returning to the frontier of the visited states is the same as hitting the boundary in the first problem starting from $1$ where $N=k-2$ (since there should be $k-1$ states total and their indexing starts at $0$). So following the result from there you get $k-3$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. I got the idea too from Joe in the following answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Equation (1.18) gives the expected time to reach either node 0 or node $N$ (either end of $N+1$ total nodes). In the simple random walk on the circle, at time $T_{k-1}$ we have $k-1$ visited points, so $N=k-2$, and when we move to the first interior point $j=1$, so $j(N-j)=k-3$

So if the expected number of steps to reach a new point is $r(k)$, we have that $r(k)= \frac{1}{2}(1)+\frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + (k-3) + r(k)\right)$

The $\frac{1}{2}(1)$ is from the probability of reaching the new point in one step, and the $\frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + (k-3) + r(k)\right)$ is from the probability of taking one step to an interior point, then an average of $(k-3)$ steps to the edge again, then an average of $r(k)$ steps to a new point.

Comment: Can I say that the node 0 is not only the starting node, but also the boundary node?

Comment: I see it now. You treat the end points of visited nodes as boundary points. Thank you for the help.

Comment: In the simple random walk on a circle, to use the results from equation (1.18), we would label the boundary nodes (of visited nodes) as $0$ and $N=k-2$.

Comment: You're welcome. If you take the time to typeset your question with MathJax, it'll be better.

Comment: First time heard of it. I will figure out what that it.

Comment: MathJax is how you type math to render well, such as typing ```$T_{k-1}$``` to render $T_{k-1}$. You can read the tutorial here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Isn't that just the latex?

Comment: I know how to use latex. I was just thinking that most part of the picture is important and I am unsure if I have to type everything down.

Comment: MathJax basically implements a subset of LaTeX math syntax. So basically you try to write LaTeX and hopefully everything you want to use is actually implemented in MathJax.

Comment: Yes, MathJax is very similar to LaTeX. I would just recommend typing  equation 1.18, then a brief description of the simple random walk on a circle, and the recurrence equation, asking what you asked. If you type that up, I'll upvote your question, and hopefully whoever downvoted that will remove it.

Comment: Mathjax sounds like "Texmaker" that I have been always using.

Comment: MathJax is actually a JavaScript library, specifically designed for rendering math on web browsers.

Comment: @Joe I have removed the pictures.

Comment: +1 Great! That should keep it from being closed.